# How to join spartan ops matchmaking

Tags: halo-4

I am finding it incredibly hard to join a multiplayer matchmaking in spartan ops. I have ended up waiting more than 15-30 mins without a single join even though there are around 150 players currently playing. I have downloaded episode 1 & 2 and able to play them offline. What am I doing wrong?

P.S: I am playing from India

Comment: is your NAT open or strict? also with only 150 people online it probably takes a while anyway

Comment: It's open and I am able to play war games without any problem. Yeah 150 is less but I guess spartan ops doesn't excite many people.

Comment: well I cant really help you then, this is just random guessing but when I played online games where 100-400 people have been active it took me at least 10 minutes to find a game too

Comment: Hmm thanks anyway. I was actually confused if spartan ops matchmaking works for those who plays with friends. Looking at my date of failure I thought it might be preferred only among clans and friends. I wish I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that since there are only ~150 players playing Spartan Ops at one time, it is actually taking you 15-30 minutes to find a game (especially since your NAT is set to open).

In my own experience (similar to RandomDisplayName in the comments), trying to join any kind of matchmaking with so few players online will take some time. I tried replaying some COD: MW2 free-for-all recently with ~500 people online, and it took around 15 minutes to connect to a game.

My only advice would be to try to play during times when there are more people online (in my experience this is usually weekday evenings and weekends). With more players online hopefully your waiting time will decrease.